# Problems with validation on Spring Boot and OVal

Tags: java, spring-boot, oval

Good day. I have app on Spring Boot 1.3 with net.sf.oval 1.85.
My model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "company")
public class Company extends BaseModel {

    @NotBlank
    @NotNull
    @Length(min = 5, max = 50)
    @Column(nullable = false, name = "name", length = 50)
    private String name;

}
```

My controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/company")
public class CompanyController {

    @Autowired
    private CompanyService companyService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Company saveCompany(@RequestBody(required = true) @Valid Company company) {
        return companyService.save(company);
    }
}
```

But @Valid did not work. How to connect spring boot and oval correctly?
In project I use only annotation without XML.
Any body have some ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanNameAutoProxyCreator](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/aop/framework/autoproxy/BeanNameAutoProxyCreator.html) for that. It should be sufficient to instantiate the beans (GuardInterceptor, BeanNameAutoProxyCreator) programmatically in your Spring configuration class, that are configured via XML in the example at [8.4.2. Guarding Spring managed beans using Spring AOP](http://oval.sourceforge.net/userguide.html#spring-integration). As value for the beanNames attribute you would use "*Controller" to match all Spring MVC Controller classes.